# How to call the default button handler in DialogPreference?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-dialog

I want my program to store credentials for a remote service, so the user would set them in preferences once and never do that again.

So I've subclassed a DialogPreference, and my class displays a nice dialog with two fields for login and password. Very good.

Now I want to validate the data when the user entered it and clicked OK, just to prevent the stupid situation when bad login is stored and we have to peek the user with warnings and ask him to go and enter the data again.

Here is the first problem: the default behaviour of the DialogPreference is closing when the button is clicked (I wonder why?)—of course I can override onDialogClosed() and validate the login there, but the dialog is closed no matter if I call super.onDialogClosed() or not.

OK, after a couple of hours searching and trying I've found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10581050/1380150) that looks great at the first glance: the click handler on the positive button allows what I want. But another problem comes: as the original click handler is replaced, the dialog doesn't close anymore. Calling super.onDialogClosed() doesn't help; I assume that this method is just a notification that doesn't provide any control.

So how to close the DialogPreference programmatically with positive result? Since I replace the default click handler for my positive button, I guess I need to call the old handler myself, but how to do that?

Comment: Did you tried calling dismiss() method of the Dialog class after you done with the validation?
like : getDialog().dismiss()

Comment: Well, this does work and even calls onDialogClosed; the only issue (minor) now is that onDialogClosed receives false, like if I canceled the dialog. That is not a problem, of course, as I can save the data in my handler and throw onDialogClosed away. I wonder why there is no accept() that would do the same but with positive result?

Comment: Actually I din't get your question regarding accept() method (my bad).. can you please describe? 
And I am adding my previous comment as answer it would be great if you accept the same ;)

Comment: Sure, I've accepted your answer. Regarding accept()—I think it is strange that the class has dismiss() method that "cancels" the dialog but doesn't have another method (it could be named accept() or alike) that would close the dialog with positive result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried calling `dismiss()` method of the Dialog class after you done with the validation?

like : `getDialog().dismiss()`